# Multiple rdpthread.exe Processes Using 100% CPU

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, central-processing-unit

I have recently created a new virtual machine (running on VMWare ESXi) running Windows Server 2008 R2. I have noticed that the machine has been running slowing and looking in Task Manager I see about 25 instances of a process "rdpthread.exe" running with user ASP.NET which is using 100% CPU....any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just confirmed that this is a virus:(